# Retirar as colunas com Null da DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Já utilizei "IS NOT NULL" no Select da Query, porém ela remove a linha inteira e no caso, eu gostaria de remover a coluna apenas. Essa tabela possui mais de 70 colunas e os Campos Null podem variar, porém quando uma coluna tiver null, ela será null a coluna inteira. Também já tentei via código, mas sem sucesso.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Precisei de duas iterações para fazer esse trabalho, uma para percorrer as colunas do datagridview e ir armazenando o nome das colunas que possuem a linha com valor null e a segunda apenas para ir removendo. Isso porque se eu removesse a coluna logo na primeira iteração, a coleção seria modificada e o resultado não seria como desejado.

```
        //lista para ir armazenando o nome das colunas que irão ser removidas
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();

        //percorre as colunas do datagridview
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            //verifica se o valor da primeira linha é igual a DBNull.Value
            if (dataGridView1[column.Index, 0].Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                //adiciona a coluna a lista para depois ser removida
                columnNames.Add(column.Name);
            }
        }

        //percorre a lista para ir removendo as colunas
        foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(dataGridView1.Columns[columnName]);
        }
```

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado Marcos! Resolveu um problema em que eu estava a dias! Parabéns!